# dijit/form/NumberTextBox Issue with value from 0 to 1

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.form

I need to create a `NumberTextBox` which can accept value from 0 to 1 in the following format:

```
0    valid
0.1  valid
0.2  valid
...
1.0  valid
1    valid
```

At the movement I am using `pattern '#.#'` but the form is invalid in this case:

```
0  invalid
1  invalid
```

How can I fix pattern for `NumberTextBox`?

http://jsfiddle.net/3ou4hkjw/7/

```
<input data-dojo-type="dijit.form.NumberTextBox" data-dojo-props="value:0.0, constraints:{min:0, max:1, pattern:'#.#', places:1}" />


dojo.require("dijit.form.NumberTextBox");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input data-dojo-type="dijit.form.NumberTextBox" data-dojo-props="value:0.0, constraints:{min:0, max:1, pattern: '0.0;1.0'}" />
```

You need to add pattern as mentioned in code snippet

[**JS FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/badrzaman/3ou4hkjw/14/#)

For more options you can look at DOJO [docs here](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dijit/form/NumberTextBox)